# How to access module from subdirectory in Python

Tags: python, python-module

I have a folder structure like so:

```
/mylib/
/mylib/__init__.py
/mylib/my_class.py
/mylib/tests/test_my_lib.py
```

In my test, I have:

```
from mylib import MyClass
import unittest
```

I'm getting:

```
  File "test_edgecast_mcc_client.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mylib import MyClass
ImportError: No module named mylib
```

Which, I think, makes sense because the import would be looking inside the tests directory for mylib when it should be looking in ../mylib?

Can anyone share some light on how to get the import to work properly?

Comment: Is `mylib` on your Python module search path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your tests package needs an `__init__.py` file too

Answer (score 0):

Add primary directory to `$PYTHONPATH`. You can do it from your `test_my_lib.py` using something like this:

```
import sys
import os.path

d = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

sys.path.insert(0, d)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this from command line and see if that eliminates the error

`export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/mylib/"`